# Material for water feed line on furnace humidifier. Latex required?

Tags: humidifier, vinyl

The water feed line on my furnace humidifier that connects to the pad started leaking, so I need to replace it.  The original was made latex 1/4" OD tubing, but the store doesn't have that size and the latex tubing they do have is MUCH more expensive than vinyl tubing.

My questions:

- Is it a problem to use Vinyl for water tubing that will end up circulating in my air?
- Will Vinyl tubing work for my situation?  Was there a reason the original had latex tubing?
- Do I need to be concerned about the temperature the tubing may reach being next to my furnace?
- Aren't there a lot of types of vinyl? Do I have to look for particular properties of my specific vinyl to make sure it would work for my situation? Or would any vinyl do?

If it helps you can see a diagram of my [HE220 humidifier](https://customer.honeywell.com/resources/techlit/TechLitDocuments/69-0000s/69-2516EF.pdf) and you can see the tubing on page 3 which also connects at the top of the pad.

Comment: Are you sure it is latex? Could be a soft vinyl or rubber. I looked at the install instructions, and various places online and nothing said latex, rubber or vinyl. However, tubing was used, which generally indicates vinyl, hose is usually rubber.

Comment: No, I'm not sure.  It was black (opaque) and squishy and the only tubing material that was remotely similar at my hardware store was latex, so I just assumed.  I called Honeywell this morning and said Vinyl or latex are both fine.

Answer (score 2):

I called Honeywell about the issue and they said both Latex and Vinyl were fine to use for the humidifier water feed tube.